# How to generate information needed for Sitecore support when creating a ticket

Tags: support

When contacting Sitecore official support, they are requesting some basic information about our solution.

What is the best and easy way to create these information ?
What tools/modules can we used to generate these info ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sitecore 8.2 has a new admin page at /sitecore/admin/SupportPackage.aspx that will gather this information into a zip package for you.  For earlier versions, you can use the [Support Package Generator](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_Support_Package_Generator.aspx?sc_lang=en), which is a windows GUI application that helps you generate the package.

Comment: Don't forget manual collection is an option as well - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/406145

Comment: For me the 8.2 ver , sitecore /supportpackage throws this error on uploading to FTP - Error: The remote server returned an error: (534) 534 Policy requires SSL. .